# Echo $curauth for user description in author page?

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

For example, i have this for an author box in single post in Wordpress:

```
$tab = str_repeat("\t", !empty($depth) ? $depth : 0);
if (is_single()) {

echo
"$tab\t\t<p>" .  get_the_author_meta('description') . "</p>\n";
```

then i want to make a code like that one to work on author page and i have this code:

```
if (is_author()) {
            // Get author data
            if(get_query_var('author_name')) :
                $curauth = get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name'));
            else :
                $curauth = get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));
            endif;
        echo "...(here i need help for that line of code)" <?php echo $curauth->description; ?> ;
```

Excuse my english !

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going:

```
<?php
if ( is_author() ) {
    $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
    if( $curauth != false ) {
        echo $curauth->description;
    } else {
        echo 'Could not get WP_User object';
    }
}
?>
```

Or somewhere on the page

```
<p>Author name:<?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?></p>
<p>Author description: <?php echo $curauth->description; ?></p>
```

Always check that `$curauth` has been filled with user data (a [`WP_User`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) object) before trying to echo any data.

More infos: http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates